# How to classify filters

Tags: dsp, fir, iir

I deal with digital signal processing which also deals with filters.
There are 2 main types of filters: Analog and Digital.
To each type there are several classifications such as:FIR/IIR/RCSR(sometimes combined like FIR And RCSR)/BIBO stable/real/rational/GLP.

Here is my question:
How to identify between *all* those classificators
I do know some about each but when I need to classify for example if it is real or not (from looking at the transfer function) I'm a bit confused
It feels that I never know ALL the charactheristics of each one of them.
Say we have a rational GLP which is not RCSR. What can I say about it's zeros in the transfer function? Today I found out that it doesn't have to have zeros at all

another more specific example:

I have this filter:

[image]

I know it is rational,real,not casual, BIBO stable and has a linear phase (meaning he is a GLP)
BUT, how do I acutally see that it is : real,not casual and BIBO stable?

and finally, does someone has some "cheatsheet" with a summary of all those classification? sadly, I couldn't find.

Thanks in advance, Roy.

Comment: this might be a better question over at dsp.stackexchange.com, where you've already got an account!

Comment: *There are 2 main types of filters: Analog and Digital.* That's **your** categorization, but there's way more ways to categorize filters: linear vs nonlinear, time-variant vs time-invariant, finite or infinite in length, …

Comment: *How to identify between all those classificators* **You can't**. Categorization is arbitrary, there's infinitely many possible classifications. Just like for cats: there's small and large cats. Fat and slim cats. Old and young cats. Dead and alive cats. Fictional and real cats. British and non-british cats. Cats with and without tail. Cats with 2 ears, and cats with a different number of ears. Cats with an even number of hairs, or with an odd number of hairs. Cats that can run faster than 30 km/h, and not. Cats that pay taxes, and those that don't. Cats that have names, and cats without…

Comment: Back to filters: even or odd length, causal or non-causal, implemented mechanically or not implemented mechanically, expensive or cheap, computationally intensive or not, already invented on 1.1.1970 or invented later, finite resolution tap filters and filters with infiinite precision in each tap, paid for by the German government filter designs, and otherwise financed designs, patented and un-patented, using an integral transform or not, differentiable in time domain or not, same for frequency domain, convergence rate exponentially bounded or not, symmetric or not, normalized in power or not…